# Импорт CSV в mySQL не полностью

Tags: php, mysql, csv, импорт

Такая ситуация: импортирую файл в таблицу базы данных в котором 2 900 000 строк и весит около 800 мб. Результат - в таблице только 400 000 примерно или 900 000 примерно, каждый раз по разному. В чем может быть проблема? Подскажите пожалуйста.
Благодарю заранее.

```
$file = fopen('registr_01.csv', 'r');
$mysqli = new mysqli ('localhost', 'root', '', 'PF_TEST_01');

while(!feof($file)) {
$mass = fgetcsv($file, 1024, ';', '"');
$j = count ($mass);

if ($j > 1) {

    $mysqli -> query (
        "INSERT INTO main (
        POLIS_SER, 
        POLIS_NUM, 
        FIO
        ) 
        VALUES (
        '{$mass [0]}',
        '{$mass [1]}',
        '{$mass [2]}'
    )");        
}

fclose ($file);
$mysqli -> close();
```

Comment: Вы не контролируете ошибки выполнения запросов к серверу, поэтому и не видите причин. Напишите логирование ошибок - узнаете, почему та или иная запись не попала в таблицу. PS. А чтобы ускорить этот кошмар, используйте `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

Comment: Включите отображение ошибок, банально может сервер отваливается из-за нехватки памяти или по таймауту.

Comment: И если все таки делать это скриптом, как сейчас, то очень рекомендую сделать `mysqli->prepare('insert .... values(?,?,?)')` _перед_ циклом, а внутри цикла выполнять только bind_param и execute (если бы использовали PDO, то могли бы вместо bind передавать свой массив значений прямо execute). Во первых это быстрее работает. Во вторых сейчас, если у вас в данных кавычки, то запрос завершается с ошибкой. А при bind он сам разберется, что делать с кавычками

Comment: Благодарю вас, буду пробовать.